# I've not downvoted any post but I lost two points. What's going on?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm confused. On my [profile  page](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/90252/scritter) a -2 showed up.

I have not received voting privileges and hasn't intentionally downvoted anyone.  How did I lose 2 points?

I am also wondering -  on my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87504/how-do-i-clear-clipboard-contents-on-samsung-galaxy-tab-s/120344#120344) where I lost the above points there is a -1 between the voting arrows.

What is it? I thought it showed accrued points. What am I missing?

Comment: Without checking: A post might have been removed where you previously earned +2 (e.g. via an edit), as your "also wondering" confirms: when that happens, rep is "undone" – i.e. downvote substracts are given back, upvote earnings taken back. At least for rep "recently earned" (not sure how far back that reaches, AFAIR something like 3 or 6 months).

Comment: None of my posts have disappeared - I corrected my own post, so doing this removed the points gained from making the post?  I hope I'm not just being dense...Does this mean I actually lost a point in answering a question?

Comment: Nope, editing a post doesn't remove previously earned rep (though as a result, a downvote might if it was a bad edit :) Firelord figured out your case meanwhile. And yes, downvotes without explanations are a problem – I wish people doing that would leave a hint in the comments, unless it's something too obvious :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the breakdown:

You had 1+5+2=8 points until an hour ago.

[image]

[image]

Then you received a downvote on a post of yours which took two points out of the total, ending up at 6 points.

[image]

Now, you pretty much had it all figured out, but you're missing the point stated in help center [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down):

<sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

> - Downvotes **remove 2 reputation from the post owner**.
> - Downvotes on answers remove 1 reputation from you, the voter.

This is simply what happened. You received a single downvote (that -1 between the arrows) on [your answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120344/96277) which took away  two points from your account and one point from the user who downvoted it.

Comment: Got it, I think... I was mistakenly seeing the downvote notification, the -1 as points not votes.  It's there anyway too find out why my answer wss downvoted?, I'd like to improve it or remove it.  btw, thanks for your time.

Comment: Why was it downvoted is an altogether different question which you should ask as a separate question (be kind). My take is that the last line seems to be a promotion for the app. It can take further edit in capitalization of words and so. Also, we use quotes not @ when we mention a post's content (not a forum but a Q/A site. See [tour]).  You may consider correcting them and for the first line of the answer, perhaps screenshots can help. // Only the downvoter can truly explain  why the post was considered not useful.